# Add double quote to array

Tags: react-native

I would like to make the array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] to become ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]. The array is from memory so i cannot set it manually. Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to literally take the strings like `1`, `2`, etc. and surround them with quotation marks:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'].map(s => `"${s}"`);
```

Output:

```
["\"1\"", "\"2\"", "\"3\"", "\"4\"", "\"5\""]
```

Where the first element `"1"` is a string comprising three characters: `"`, `1`, and `"`.

Comment: I think the idea was not to introduce quotation marks.  It was just to convert the numbers to strings.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial interpretation as well. Since that was already covered by the other answer, I decided to cover the alternative interpretation, hence the downvotes I suppose...

Comment: Your illustration of the supposed "output" is a little bit misrepresentative.  The actual output is more likely to be displayed by any reasonable debugger or console.log as: `["\"1\"", "\"2\"", "\"3\"", "\"4\"", "\"5\""]`